Why Stack Exchange is not open-source?
Stack Exchange websites are for developers, who like open-source.
So why they're not open-source?
Is there a reason for why they're not open-source?
Is it a "selling" point or they just don't want us to see their code?

Will Stack Overflow's engine be (someday, or ever) open sourced?

Very related: Are there any clones/alternatives for running a Stack Exchange style Q&A site?

Because it is a company (well more accurately it’s owned by a company) that wants to make money. Being open source would allow for a lot of clones. Particularly with the whole “we have no regard for the community” thing, myself and many other users would probably move to an SE clone run by people who care about the community and the quality of the site. It would also make it for difficult for the company to make money, because someone would probably just copy SE and then they make the money from ads if anyone visits the clone. They could also just decide to remove ads and most people don’t like ads so…

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
